# Nvidia GeForce 750m resolution weird overscan on reboot problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, resolution, macbook-pro

Ok, so it's not exactly overscanning, but thats the best way I can explain it.

Here is whats happening. I start my computer the resolution is 2880x1800 and every thing is good.

But I am not super human and I can't read the teeny tiny text, so I open my nvidia-settings and change the resolution to 1920x1200 and everything works as expected.

**But** after reboot the resolution is still the same, however I can push my cursor to the right edge of the screen and my "ViewPort" moves to the right. It's like the screen is bigger than the current viewport. How can I fix this?

**OtherInfo**

- Computer: MacBook Pro 11,3
- OS: Linux 14.04
- Graphics: Nvidia G-force 750M
- Drivers: 64bit 346.16

#### Edit

- Drivers Ive tried and still have the same problem:

  - 340.xx
  - 331.xx
  - 346.xx

Comment: I used 346.16 for my MacBook Pro 11,3 they seemed to work the best. I tried all the compatible ones and this 346.16 was the best for me.

Comment: Why don't you try the lastest driver nvidia?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work on my mackbook.

Answer (score 0):

Try purging NVIDIA driver 340.58 from system. Install NVIDIA driver 331.104 and reboot. I am using NVIDIA GPU G-force 730 and it will not work right with version 340 but works perfect with 331. Make sure you purge all traces of other drivers from system before installing the NEW driver.

Comment: Those were the first drivers that I had installed and I have the same problem :-(